# What is a good zip library for iOS that is ARC compatible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, zip, automatic-ref-counting

I'm looking to unzip a file in an iOS app, but can't find a library that is ARC compatible.

Comment: They're all 'arc compatible' - just turn off arc for that new code (if there is new code).

Comment: Is "ARC", in this case, referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_(file_format\) ?

Answer (score 2):

[Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) works pretty well. I'm not sure what you mean by "ARC compatible," though. If it's in C or C++, ARC isn't relevant. If it's in ObjC, you can just turn off ARC for the files you need to ( [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) )